# Is it true that we have$\frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i}\leq C$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Here's the problem:

> Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that
> $$
> \frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i}\leq C
> $$
> for all $x_i\geq 1$?

I believe the statement is positive and I actually have found a number (to be shown below) in terms of limit process, yet I am not quite sure about the validity of my work.

**Question.**

1. Does my work make any sense?
2. Is there any alternative way to find a $C>0$ in question? (Maybe without using Real Analysis as I did)

**My Work.**

To see it, let $f\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)=\frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$ on $A=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_i\geq 1 \text{, for each $i$}\right\}$. Since $f\to 0$ if $\left|x\right|\to \infty$, there exists $M_1>0$ such that
$$
f\left(x\right)\leq M_1
$$
if $\left|x\right|>N$.

On the other hand, $f$ attains its absolute maximum, say $M_2$,  in $A \cap \left\{\left|x\right|\leq N\right\}$ since $f$ is continuous.

Therefore, put $C=\max\left\{M_1,M_2\right\}$ and we obtain (3). Note that $C$ is independent of $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.

Comment: There is no $C$ independent of $n$ and the $x_i$'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_k = \max_{i=1}^n x_i$. Then
$$
1 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le (n+1) x_k \le (n+1) \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \, ,
$$
because all $x_i \ge 1$.

So $C=n+1$ does the job. Setting all $x_i =1$ shows that this is the best possible constant.

---

Alternatively: $f\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)=\frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$ is decreasing in each variable, so that
$$
 f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \le f(1, \ldots, 1) = n+1 \, .
$$

---

With respect to your proof:
$$
 f(x_1, 1, \ldots, 1) = \frac{x_1 + n}{x_1}
$$
does *not* converge to zero for $x_1\to \infty$.

You could (for example) argue that $f$ is decreasing in each variable separately, so that $x_k \ge R$ implies
$$
 f(x_1, \ldots, x_k) \le f(1, \ldots, 1, x_k, 1,\ldots, 1)
= \frac{n+R}{R} 
$$
and that is $\le 2$ for $R \ge n$. It follows that $f$ is *bounded* outside of the hypercube $C_n = \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid 1 \le x_i \le n \text{ for } i=1, \ldots, n \}$.

Then continue as before: $f$ is continuous inside the compact set $C_n$.

Comment: Your first method is strikingly simple to me!! That's awesome. Also, thank you for pointing out the flaw that I did not realize!